# Workstation or smartphone

Tags: pc, smartphones

I'm in a dilemma with a decision. Should I sell my pc work station that I don't fully utilize for a good smart phone?

I generally only do web browsing and YouTube watching. Sporadic document editing. Might do some low end video editing, all which decent smartphones seem to do well. So I'm thinking just get and use a good smartphone (essentially tiny computers) and just use a usb-c dongle or Bluetooth to connect peripherals and monitors. Plus I can always use an "OS on a stick" with another computer if I needed an actual pc for anything.

Any thoughts or suggestions?
I have hp z2 g5 i7 10700 mini vs smartphone (high end vs mid end)
I'm thinking Samsung Galaxy Note would be adequate. Plus I like that I can put it in a Faraday bag/case when I want to be OFFLINE

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a bigger screen, so a Samsung Tab S9 with a cover and keyboard.  I bought one for my wife recently.  The bulge holds the stylus.  And it has a mouse/track pad built in.  You can also use the touch screen.  The windows (apps) work just like windows.  You can move, minimize or resize etc.

Its really the best of all worlds.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thx Rohit, but it's either phone or pc. Phone would be connected to a tv or monitor if being used as pc at the time.

Comment: And thx again, but i prefer using peripherals. I use an extra mouse with my laptop on the road (at a desk), and docking station at home/office. But this question is referring to desktop or smartphone. Just use the money selling the Z2 G5 to get a better high end smartphone. They seem to do everything I'd need to do. But surely I'm not thinking of or missing something. Then again, I'm actually wanting to ditch smartphone and go back to regular mobile phone.

Answer (score 0):

I have an old Galaxy Note 9 and the desktop functionality is great. However, I recommend that you always have some access to a traditional desktop (even if it's through a local library) because you will run into compatibility issues. Although the instances may be rare, it can ruin your day if you get a bill you can't pay without using some old version of java that your phone doesn't support.

P.S. You can get a refurbished last-gen top of the line phone for cheap. Ex: Note 9 for $200 is quite a bargain when the latest version is x10 the cost for 20% more performance.